# Pan effect in android custome view

Tags: android

I have created one custom view which is having image and user can pan and zoom image.zoom effect is working properly but when I am moving image its moving perfect but when next time again I am moving image first it gets to its initial location i.e. x=0,y=0 and then its again moving from there but I want image to move from its last position.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        if (!flag) {
        canvas.translate(dxFactor, dyFactor);
        }
        image.draw(canvas);
    }


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        dxFactorLast = event.getX();
        dyFactorLast = event.getY();
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        dxFactorCurrent=event.getX();
        dyFactorCurrent=event.getY();
        if(dxFactorCurrent!=dxFactorLast || dyFactorCurrent!=dyFactorLast)
        {
        dxFactor = dxFactorCurrent - dxFactorLast;
        dyFactor = dyFactorCurrent - dyFactorLast;
        flag = false;
        invalidate();
        }
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        break;
    }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Image is moving correctly and smoothly but when next time I am moving image its not moving from its current location instead of that its getting shifted to its initial location and again moving from their.